# How to use "cache control max age directive from cloudfront" in AEM?

Tags: aem

I need to set the caching duration for the pdf documents as 1 hour. So after every hour, the PDFs get refreshed. I found over the internet that we can use cache control-max age header as below-

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600
```

so that it will tell cloudfront to keep the PDFs in the cache for 3600 seconds(1 hour).

But I am not sure where to put this code. Do I need to put this in the dispatcher? If yes, how? Can anyone please provide some code snippet for the same?

Also, we have included "expires.rules" file in the dispatcher which has the below code-

```
ExpiresActive on
ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

Header append Cache-Control "public"
Header add X-ServiceProvider "Test"

#PDF
ExpiresByType application/pdf                       "access plus 1 hour"
```

Is it doing the same thing as max-age header?

It will be really helpful if someone can explain this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to set the cache headers in the Apaches VirutalHost definition. Normally the settings differ by file-type and path. Also make sure that you differentiate between author and publisher.

Here are some examples

```
# Cache JS+CSS with MD5 Hash for 30 days
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*(\.min)?\.[a-f0-9]{25,32}\.(js|css)$" immutable_resource=true
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000" env=immutable_resource


# Cache Images for 30 days
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(etc|content)/.*\.(svg|png|gif|jpeg|jpg)$" image_resource=true
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000" env=image_resource

# Cache Fonts for 30 days
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/etc/.*\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$" font_resource=true
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=2592000" env=font_resource

# Cache HTML documents for 2 hours (in this example everything is served with /content/...)
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/content/myproject/.*\.html$" html_document=true
# Treat vanity URLs as HTML documents too
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.html)?$" html_document=true
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200" env=html_document
```